# Hoptoad Java deployment tracking

Tags: java, jsf, deployment, hoptoad

I'm currently using Hoptoad to track exceptions in my Java application using Frog4J (http://freeasinbeard.org/post/1150100907/frog4j-simpler-integration-of-hoptoad-and-log4j).

This is working really well for tracking the exceptions but I would really love to be able to track my deployments with Hoptoad as well (http://help.hoptoadapp.com/kb/api-2/deploy-tracking).

I know of no current way to tell Hoptoad when I'm deploying and so currently all of the errors need to be marked as resolved manually. We currently have quite a backlog of fixed exceptions that we would really just like to mark as resolved at once and indeed mark them all as resolved every deployment.

I know this is quite an easy step when using Ruby but I have been unable to find a way to do so with Java. Of course if you have any other suggestions of how to tell Hoptoad when I deploy using part of the API that would be equally as awesome as I could easily incorporate that into the deployment process.

Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to trigger this manually using curl.

For future reference the syntax is:

```
curl --data "api_key=###&deploy[rails_env]=###&deploy[svn_revision]=###&deploy[scm_repository]=###&deploy[local_username]=###" http://hoptoadapp.com/deploys.txt
```

`###` will need to be replaced with your particulars.

Thanks to the some hints found here:
http://help.hoptoadapp.com/discussions/questions/391-documentation-for-deploy-tracking-api